# SwiftUI button inactive inside NavigationLink item area

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a view for a list item that displays some news cards within a navigationLink.

I am supposed to add a like/unlike button within each news card of navigationLink, without being took to NavigationLink.destination page.

It seems like a small button inside a big button. 
When you click that small one, execute the small one without executing the bigger one.
(note: the click area is covered by the two buttons, smaller one has the priority)
(In javascript, it seems like something called .stopPropaganda)

This is my code:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.newsData.newsList, id:\.self) { articleID in
                    NavigationLink(destination: NewsDetail(articleID: articleID)) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(newsTitle)

                            Button(action: {
                                self.news.isBookmarked.toggle()
                            }) {
                                if self.news.isBookmarked {
                                    Image(systemName: "bookmark.fill")
                                } else {
                                    Image(systemName: "bookmark")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently, the button action (like/dislike) will not be performed as whenever the button is pressed, the navigationLink takes you to the destination view. 
I have tried [this almost same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59403136/7730162) but it cannot solve this problem.

Is there a way that makes this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: NavigationLink is kind of button, so... just curious, why do you put button into label of NavigationLink, ie another button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does exactly what you want.

```
struct Artcle {
  var text: String
  var isBookmarked: Bool = false
}

struct ArticleDetail: View {
  var article: Artcle
  var body: some View {
    Text(article.text)
  }
}

struct ArticleCell: View {
  var article: Artcle
  var toggle: () -> ()
  @State var showDetails = false
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text(article.text)
        Spacer()
        Button(action: {
            self.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: article.isBookmarked ? "bookmark.fill" : "bookmark").padding()
        }
        .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
    }
    .overlay(
        NavigationLink(destination: ArticleDetail(article: article), isActive: $showDetails) { EmptyView() }
    )
    .onTapGesture {
        self.showDetails = true
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {

  @State var articles: [Artcle]

  init() {
    _articles = State(initialValue: (0...10).map { Artcle(text: "Article \($0 + 1)") })
  }

  func toggleArticle(at index: Int) {
    articles[index].isBookmarked.toggle()
  }

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(Array(self.articles.enumerated()), id:\.offset) { offset, article in
                ArticleCell(article: article) {
                    self.toggleArticle(at: offset)
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

as of XCode 12.3, the magic is to add .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) or BorderlessButtonStyle to the button, when said button is on the same row as a NavigationLink within a List.

Without this particular incantation, the entire list row gets activated when the button is pressed and vice versa (button gets activated when NavigationLink is pressed).