# SwiftUI Button does not perform action

Tags: swiftui

I have this peace of code that I have done to create a custom animated button

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomLoginButtons<ButtonText: View>: View { // it can conforms to whatever I want as long it conforms to View protocol
    
    let buttonAction: () -> Void //buttons returns that, just an empty closure
    let buttonText: ButtonText // generics for button text whatever i want
        
    @State private var pressed = false // variable that hold states of a button
    
    init(buttonAction: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder buttonText: () -> ButtonText ) {
        //the @escaping it means here that the action will be ignored here, for now, beacause it will be used somewhere else
        self.buttonAction = buttonAction
        self.buttonText = buttonText()// here its being initialized for building the button text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: buttonAction) {// here i am passing the action closure to be executed
            buttonText
                .padding()
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)/* infinity meas that the component will fit the entire view, that way
                 i can set the size in the view that i want to use this button*/
                .background(Capsule().fill(Color.blue))
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30).stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1.5))
                .scaleEffect(self.pressed ? 1.2 : 1.0)
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: .infinity, maximumDistance: .infinity, pressing: { pressing in
                    let impactHeavy = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .soft)
                               impactHeavy.impactOccurred()
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2)) {
                        self.pressed = pressing
                    }
                }, perform: { })
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is currently when I tap on this button, the action is not performed, and I don't know why.

```
CustomLoginButtons(buttonAction: {
    print("Tapped")
}) {
    Text("Login")
}
```

that is how I am calling this button.

Comment: found the awnser in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58037105/how-to-make-zoom-in-zoom-out-button-animation-on-tap-gesture-in-swiftui

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make zoom in zoom out button animation on tap gesture in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58037105/how-to-make-zoom-in-zoom-out-button-animation-on-tap-gesture-in-swiftui)